# Adding "active" class to each li using JQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, ajax

I'm trying to add class active to each li tag in my website but I think something is wrong in my code and I don't know what is it, anyone can help. I will be appreciated.

```js
 $(function () {
     var pgurl = window.location.search;
     $("li a").each(function () {
         if ($(this).attr("href") == pgurl || $(this).attr("href") == '')
             $(this).addClass("active");
     });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="menu" class="bg-blue dker">
    <li class="nav-header">القائمة</li>
    <li class="nav-divider"></li>
    <li class="">
        <a href="#">
            <i class="fa fa-tasks"></i>
            <span class="link-title">الأقسام والأصناف</span>
            <span class="fa arrow"></span>
        </a>
        <ul class="collapse">
            <li class="">
                <a href="?page=Hot-drinks-section">
                    المشروبات الساخنة</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="?page=Soft-drinks-section">
                    المشروبات الباردة</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="?page=Food-section">
                    المأكولات</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="">
        <a href="?page=Make-an-order">
            <i class="fa fa-plus"></i> <span class="link-title">إضافة طلب جديد</span>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You need to add active class to each li or a specific one ?

Comment: I need to add active class for the page I opened for example. I'm in Home page I want the li of home page has the active class and so on...

Comment: Ok, but the situation cannot be replicated in this snippet. So I think the problem is, currently you are adding the active class to the `a` under `li`, not to the `li`. Is that the expected behaviour or you want to add to the li itself?

Comment: Yes, I want to add to the li itself

Comment: I just realized that I have to use `$(this).closest('li')` this is work thanks bro.

Comment: Yes, or you can use `parent()`, so that it will select the `li`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below snippet.

The change I made is `$(this).parent().addClass("active");`, so that the active class will be added to `li`, not `a`.

```js
$(function () {
     var pgurl = window.location.search;
     $("li a").each(function () {
         if ($(this).attr("href") == pgurl || $(this).attr("href") == '')
             $(this).parent().addClass("active");
     });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="menu" class="bg-blue dker">
    <li class="nav-header">القائمة</li>
    <li class="nav-divider"></li>
    <li class="">
        <a href="#">
            <i class="fa fa-tasks"></i>
            <span class="link-title">الأقسام والأصناف</span>
            <span class="fa arrow"></span>
        </a>
        <ul class="collapse">
            <li class="">
                <a href="?page=Hot-drinks-section">
                    المشروبات الساخنة</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="?page=Soft-drinks-section">
                    المشروبات الباردة</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="?page=Food-section">
                    المأكولات</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="">
        <a href="?page=Make-an-order">
            <i class="fa fa-plus"></i> <span class="link-title">إضافة طلب جديد</span>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add class on a parent element example: `$(this).parent().addClass("active");`

Try below code

```
$(function () {
 var pgurl = window.location.search;
 $("li a").each(function () {
     if ($(this).attr("href") == pgurl || $(this).attr("href") == '')
      $(this).parent().addClass("active");
 });
});
```